# Extending linear continuous functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $E$, $F$ be normed vector spaces and $M$ a subspace of $E$.

I'm trying to find an example of a function $f:M\to F$ such that $f$ is linear and continuous but that you can't extend it to $\tilde{f}: E\to F$ linear and continuous.

I already know that you can extend every linear function into another linear function but I can't find and example where the continuity fails.

Comment: You could look at $F = M$.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this thread][1] and see comments by Yemon Choi.


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68817/under-what-conditions-a-bounded-linear-map-can-be-extended